# Modify dataType for columns with data in Oracle using Liquibase

Tags: oracle, liquibase

I am trying to modify the dataType from NUMBER(10,0) to NUMBER(30,0) against a database with data in these columns. I have to use liquibase for this. I am using the following:

```
<modifyDataType tableName="tableName" columnName="columnsName" newDataType="NUMBER(38,0)"/>
```

But for the tables with data in the columns I get the following error:

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01440: column to be modified must be empty to decrease precision or scale
```

And the column is not migrated. Can columns with data not be migrated to a new type by this method?

Comment: Did you solve this issue?
How did you manage the data migration?

Answer (score 1):

Its not liquibase, its the oracle engine which throws this error. Liquibase actually converts `modifyDataType` to an alter table statement. So your statement which goes to oracle engine will be like:

```
ALTER TABLE tableName MODIFTY columnsName NUMBER(38,0);
```

Now  `modifyDataType` will return any error returned as a result of the generated sql statement.

Answer (score 0):

Check to make sure the column has the dataType you suspect.  Your migration will work IFF the original dataType is NUMBER(N,0) where N < 38.